# Add condition to join linq to object c#

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to add a condition to the below query based on another property

eg"and a.City=b.City" .How would I do it  .

Currenty query

```
var result = firstCollection.Join(secondCollection, 
                                  a => a.CustomerId, 
                                  b => b.CustomerId,  //TO ADD "and a.City=b.City" 
                                  GetDifferences)
                            .SelectMany(x => x)
                            .Where(x => x != null).ToList();
```

In sql I would do:

```
Select * from firstCollection a 
INNER JOIN secondCollection B on a.CustomerId=b.CustomerId and a.city=b.city
```

many thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anonymous types:

```
var result = firstCollection.Join(secondCollection, 
                                  a => new { a.CustomerId, a.City }
                                  b => new { b.CustomerId, b.City },
                                  GetDifferences)
                            .SelectMany(x => x)
                            .Where(x => x != null).ToList();
```

Comment: THanks that helped.what about match on customerId but I want to know all the ones where they dont match on city.Basically give me all records that have the same customerId but their city is a mismatch.sorry about this .just occured to me i need to do this